# Jest snapshot not generating snapshot and failing test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Trying to work with Jest snapshot testing within react. When i run yarn test, it passes the script execution but fails the snapshot test and generates no snapshots.

No clue what to try, seems like some really straightforward code.

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import IndexPage from '../Page';

describe('test script execution', () => {
  test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
  });
});

it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<IndexPage />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Passes the first test, and fails the second. Along with failing to generate a snapshot or snapshot directory.

Edit: Index Page

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import Input from '../components/Input';
import Output from '../components/Output';
import OutputHTML from '../components/OutputHtml';

const styles = theme => ({
  gridItem: { padding: `0 ${theme.spacing.unit * 2}px` },
});

const IndexPage = ({ classes }) => (
  <Grid container>
    <Grid className={classes.gridItem} item xs={12} md={6}>
      <Input />
    </Grid>
    <Grid className={classes.gridItem} item xs={12} md={6}>
      <Output />
    <OutputHTML />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
);
```

Comment: Provide code of IndexPage component pls

Comment: Do you have functions on IndexPage component? and did you install enzyme?

Comment: Try replacing IndexPage with a <div /> with a props such as className and see if that works. I imagine that your component may not be returning anything?? Please update with source  code to help!

Comment: Seems like pressing `u` will update snapshot. Not sure if snapshot was created however.

Comment: @Rikin No snapshot was created

Comment: @Neil tried that with the same results. Have also tried replacing the div with an href to the website where its hosted with the same results.

Comment: Add the index page, also are you use create-react-app?

Comment: @Neil Index page added. I am also using create-react-app.

Comment: You have a required prop called classes, have you added this object?

Comment: What does the test say when it passes? Also have you checked if the file is hidden in the IDE?